# Android Camera Bug

Tags: android, android-camera

i want to make a very simple application and I want to open the camera in a Relative Layout, but I see only a black screen instead of the camera.
The code i very simple

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void button(android.view.View v){
    android.hardware.Camera camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.video);
    SurfaceView surfaceView = new SurfaceView(getApplicationContext());

    relativeLayout.addView(surfaceView);

    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {};

}
```

}

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you want to do after you open the camera?

Comment: Can you mark my answer as the answer to your question in case you're satisfied with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code below you can open the camera when clicking on the button, take a picture and display it in your image view.
Don't forget to edit `YOUR_PROJECT` before testing/using it.

**Your Java file:**

```
package YOUR_PROJECT;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initialize Image view and Buttons
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Button btnCapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_camera);

    //Set listener on Capture button
    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent c = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); //Implicit Intent
            startActivityForResult(c, 0);
        }
    });


}

//Override method onActivityResult used to retreive the image
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap m = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    iv.setImageBitmap(m);
    iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
}
}
```

**Your XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="YOUR_PROJECT.MainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_camera"
        android:text="Camera"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="106dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```